# How do I use multiple parameters with the performSelector: method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

Do I use withObject:? And if so, could I just pass, say an NSNumber?

How would it appear in the method's signature?

```
- (void)methodName:(NSTimer *)timer withObject:(NSNumber *)value {}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an NSArray object or NSDictionary which encapsulates multiple dataobjects into one! In example:

```
NSArray * myDataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],@"A String", nil];

[self performSelector:@selector(doStuff:) withObject:myDataArray afterDelay:1.0];

-(void)doStuff:(NSArray *)array{
   NSNumber * myNumber = [array objectAtIndex:0];
   NSNumber * myNumber2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];
   NSString * myString = [array objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

Comment: you can also import <objc/message.h> and call objc_msgSend to pass as many arguments as you need, without needing to modify the method to use an nsarray as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass at most two parameters directly, using `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` declared in `NSObject` protocol.

Using your example, the selector would be `@selector(methodName:withObject:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can, however, pass an `NSDictionary`, to/from which you can pack and extract multiple objects.

Also, have a look at the `NSInvocation` class.